# Instance member can not be used in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, instance

The project is to create a JSON object.

code is below :

```
public class RegisterIn {

    private var appID : String = ""                             

    private static let JK_appID : String = "appID"

    init(appID: String) {
        self.appID = appID
    }

    class getJSONObject : RegisterIn {
        let jsonObject : [String : AnyObject] =
            [ 
                JK_appID : appID   //< The following error shows on this line
            ]
    }
}
```

This line always appears [image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

You declare "getJSONObject" class (not a method) derived from RegisterIn class inside super class. Why?

## 2

```
let jsonObject : [String : AnyObject] =
        [ 
            RegisterIn.JK_appID : appID   
        ]
```

you can use const values here but not instance memeber (of derived class)

## 3

this code works in playground:

```
import UIKit

public class RegisterIn {
    
    var appID : String = ""
    
    private static let JK_appID : String = "appID"
    
    init(appID: String) {
        self.appID = appID
    }
    
}

class getJSONObject : RegisterIn {
    let jsonObject : [String : AnyObject]
    override init(appID: String) {
        jsonObject =
            [
                RegisterIn.JK_appID : appID
        ]
        super.init(appID: appID)
    }
}

let testGetJSONObject = getJSONObject(appID: "test")
```

Answer (score 1):

`appID` is a instance variable but `getJSONObject` is a class method. So it will not work. You have to redesign it somehow.

Comment: How about delete the getJSONObject class? It seems still not working

Comment: @HungCLo your current code is pointless and I cannot advise to you just delete stuff around. Post whole code file and tell me what do you want to get :)

Comment: Hello Arsen~, actually I'm translating a java code to swift. Maybe is not good to post the code here?